# Unexplainable behaviour of an observable value within Angular 5 form

Tags: angular, observable, angular-forms, reactive

Here is the code of the Angular component that can be run at https://plnkr.co/edit/eEXt9JD3OO5rRl3p37Je?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div  *ngIf="currentNumber$ | async as currentNumber">
    <b>{{currentNumber}}</b>
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="simpleForm">
    <input type="number" formControlName="number" />
  </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  primeNumbers$ : Observable<number>;
  simpleForm : FormGroup;
  constructor() {
    this.primeNumbers$ = Observable.from([3,5,7]);
    this.simpleForm = new FormGroup({
      number : new FormControl(1);
    })
  }
  get currentNumber$() : Observable<number>{
    return this.primeNumbers$.filter(n=>n===this.simpleForm.controls["number"].value);
  }
}
```

It works as desired : when I type one of 3,5,7 numbers in the input of the form, it appears on the top of the form which means that currentNumber$ observable IS updated when "number" control changes its value. How is it even possible? How does angular understand when to update the observable in this situation? Let's say that async pipe subscribes to the observable. But how does the component understands that the new observable value should be emitted when a form control's value changes? there is only reference to the form control and it's hidden deeply in the filter predicate

Answer (score 4):

The magical concoction is because you use the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), which does the evaluation of the observables for you in the `html` template a.k.a it subscribes to the observables and react to the emission of the observables.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

Edit:

The reason why typing in the input causes the html to change is slightly complicated. You will need to understand the [lifecycle hooks of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). But here goes:

It works because the moment you type a value in the input form, it triggers the `ngOnChanges()` life cycle hook. Angular will evaluates all the bindings, including this one `*ngIf="currentNumber$ | async as currentNumber"`. Now because your `currentNumber$` is gonna filter out the numbers based on the `current` value of the form (which by then is already updated), hence it only showed the filtered numbers. Here's the sequence of events.

1. Component initialize

   - `this.simpleForm.controls["number"].value` contains `null`
2. You type in `5` in the input.
3. You triggered the `ngOnChange` cycle hook.
4. `this.simpleForm.controls["number"].value` now contains `5`
5. Angular then reevaluates the every binding.
6. `currentNumber$()` gets executed.

   - it filters the `primeNumber$` based on your `this.simpleForm.controls["number"].value`, which now contains 5
7. Angular now refreshes every binded properties
8. `currentNumber$()` function returns 5, after filtering
9. `async` pipe subscribes to the data (which already have)
10. HTML shows `5`

Comment: Thanks for the side note! :-)

Comment: But okay, let's say that async subscribes to the observable. But how does the component understands that the new observable value should be emitted when a form control's value changes? there is only reference to the form control and it's hidden deeply in the filter predicate

Comment: @sovo2014 because of this `this.simpleForm.controls["number"].value`. The `.value` property of a `FormControl` will always return the *current* value of the input, and hence, the behaviour.

Comment: I know that the reference to the form control's value is in there. I don't understand HOW components understands that it's there. The only way I can see is parsing the source code, building AST tree, etc.

Comment: I see. So it's no magic. It's just Angular so stupid that it "reevaluates" every binding even though it can stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentNumber$` observable is called each and every time when anything on the form changes. Try putting a `console.log` in it, like

```
get currentNumber$() : Observable<number>{
  console.log("observable called")
  return this.primeNumbers$.filter(n=>n===this.simpleForm.controls["number"].value);
}
```

And you will see that it's called not only when the input changes, but also when the form is initialized, and so on..

The number appearing / disappearing is just the result of the observable filter having or not having a value.